# How do I graph a line when rise=x?

Tags: slope

I have the inequality $x+3y<21$.
I have rearranged to y-intercept form to give me $y<-x/3+7$.
I must have missed something in learning to graph in this form because I'm very unsure on how to graph a line when slope =$x$.

Comment: Use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$-x/3 = -\frac x3 = -\frac13 x$$

So $y < -x/3 + 7$ is the same as $y < -\dfrac13x + 7$.